# Card View Strip like Field Trip App

Tags: google-maps, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to implement something like this screenshot(Field Trip App).
Its a card strip at the bottom of map.

[image]

[image]

So I implemented a map view and recycleview and cardview, everything working fine, but unable to get the effect on focus, I want, when the cardview get focus the size of cardview must increase to show the selection.

Thanks, Please help.

Comment: You can tell if the current `cardview` get focus on the `RecyclerView.State` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.State.html).It contains useful information about the current RecyclerView state like target scroll position or view focus. Then you can use `setCardElevation` in `cardView` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#setCardElevation(float)) make some chang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using [MaterialLeanBack](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialLeanBack) Library.

[image]